# Where can I find a map of US county boundaries that reasonably shows the boundaries over bodies of water?

Tags: data, license, boundaries, county, water

Census, ESRI, and others provide shapefiles and feature classes of US county boundaries, but all the data sets I can find seem to clip the boundaries at the shoreline. So they really only show the boundaries over land, but not over water, that is, water bodies along a boundary are shown to not be in any county.

I need a similar data source that shows the boundaries between US counties over both land and water. Great accuracy is not needed, I just need data that resemble the typical printed map where there is one relatively smooth  boundary between adjacent counties (for example) following the course of a river, instead of two boundaries between the adjacent counties.

I would have assumed that Census and others start with maps that have the true boundaries, but I guess my search skills are not good enough to find such sources.

Any idea where I might find such a data set?

Comment: PLSS shapefiles show the Riparian Boundaries, but not all states are PLSS. If you really want accuracy you'll need to search recorded surveys.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Pointdump:  Edited question to clarify your latter point.

Comment: **Which country?** Lots of countries have counties.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Did you have a look at OpenStreetMap data?

Answer (score 1):

Update.  The US Census Bureau posts the unclipped US county boundaries here:
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2021/COUNTY/ under the name tl_2021_us_county.zip

To those interested in county boundaries for other nations, the suggestion by Babel to look at OpenStreetMap is correct.

Comment: Jim, your answer of Census TIGER files is going to be your best bet for an authoritative source for county boundaries.  Boundaries over water are always a mess for many reasons, but their simplification is to get around the coastline paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox It is an error you have to manage, and your audience should be aware of it as well, as needed.